# json2token not found when using the Donut VisionEncoderDecoderModel from Huggingface transformers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to fine-tune a Donut (Document Understanding) Huggingface Transformer model, but am getting hung up trying to create a `DonutDataset` object. I have the following code (running in google colab):

```
!pip install transformers datasets sentencepiece donut-python

from google.colab import drive
from donut.util import DonutDataset
from transformers import DonutProcessor, VisionEncoderDecoderModel, VisionEncoderDecoderConfig

drive.mount('/content/drive/')
projectdir = 'drive/MyDrive/donut'


donut_version = 'naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2'  # 'naver-clova-ix/donut-base'
config = VisionEncoderDecoderConfig.from_pretrained(donut_version)
config.decoder.max_length = 768

processor = DonutProcessor.from_pretrained(donut_version)
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained(donut_version, config=config)


train_dataset = DonutDataset(f'{projectdir}/input_doc_images', 
                             model,
                             #'naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2',
                             max_length=config.decoder.max_length,
                             split="train", 
                             task_start_token="", 
                             prompt_end_token="",
                             sort_json_key=True,
                             )
```

...however, the last line is throwing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9d831be996e6> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 max_length = 768
----> 4 train_dataset = DonutDataset(f'{projectdir}/input_doc_images', 
      5                              model,
      6                              #'naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2',

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1612             if name in modules:
   1613                 return modules[name]
-> 1614         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
   1615             type(self).__name__, name))
   1616 

AttributeError: 'VisionEncoderDecoderModel' object has no attribute 'json2token'
```

I'm a little confused because my `model` object is a `'naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-cord-v2'` model, which according to [this line from the model.py of the Donut github repo](https://github.com/clovaai/donut/blob/master/donut/model.py#L498) seems to suggest does in fact have a `json2token` method???

What am I missing?

btw, you can view/copy my underlying data (images and json-lines metdata file) from my google drive 'donut' folder here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gsr7d7Exvtx5PqjZQv2nXP9-pPDUEIOx?usp=sharing

Comment: Which verison of transformers are you using?

Comment: transformers 4.30.0

Answer (score 1):

To use the `DonutDataset` correctly, you should use the model class from `donut` instead of `transformers`, and the `json2token` function would work correctly e.g.

```
from donut.util import DonutDataset
from donut import DonutModel
from transformers import DonutProcessor, VisionEncoderDecoderModel, VisionEncoderDecoderConfig

import torch

pretrained_model = DonutModel.from_pretrained(
    "naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-rvlcdip",
    ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

pretrained_model.encoder.to(torch.bfloat16)


train_dataset = DonutDataset(f'my_dataset/', 
                             pretrained_model,
                             max_length=config.decoder.max_length,
                             split="train", 
                             task_start_token="", 
                             prompt_end_token="",
                             sort_json_key=True,
                             )
```

Note that the `json2token` function is in the `donut` repo https://github.com/clovaai/donut/blob/master/donut/model.py#L498 for the `DonutModel` object.

And if we look at the `transformers`, there's **no** `json2token` https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/vision_encoder_decoder/modeling_vision_encoder_decoder.py#L151 for the `VisionEncoderDecoderModel` object.

---

To use the model from `transformers` instead of `donut`, you might need to read the data differently and **not** use `donut.util.DonutDataset` re-create the dataset into Huggingface friendly dataset, like this:

```
import PIL.Image

from datasets import Dataset

i1 = PIL.Image.open('my_dataset/alex_cannon_dep_first_page.png')
i2 = PIL.Image.open('my_dataset/mcentee_dep_first_page.png')

train_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({'images': [i1, i2]})
```

Then you have to do all the features processing by yourself before feeding it to the model, see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/donut

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Alvas! this is definitely on the path of what I was looking for, as I was tying myself in knots going down the more complicated way via transformers. I now have this warning tho:
```
Some weights of DonutModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-rvlcdip and are newly initialized because the shapes did not match:
```
with several lines that look like this:
```
- encoder.model.layers.1.downsample.reduction.weight: found shape torch.Size([512, 1024]) in the checkpoint and torch.Size([256, 512]) in the model instantiated
```

Comment: ...the warning ends with "You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference." ...but I'm thinking I have definitely enough data to fine-tune for my task, but not sure I have enough data to retrain several layers from scratch/initialization. Can you help me understand how I might remedy this? Or if I'm overestimating the issue here?